# jQuery count how many tick boxes some browsers reversing the calculation?

Tags: jquery, math, browser, input

I have a simple script i wrote to count how many tick boxes are ticked and show/hide content for them. It works fine in some browsers but even testing 2 macs with FF as well both return different. ie. if no boxes it would return laggard, more than this is should change the div on display.

The odd thing is, some browsers are reversing this, e.g. if all the boxes are ticked it shows laggard instead of innovator.

Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
//alert($('input:checked').size())
//if laggard
if ($('input:checked').size() < 1) {
$("div#four").show();
$("div#one").hide();
$("div#two").hide();
$("div#three").hide();
$("div#EM").hide();
}
//late majority
else if ($('input:checked').size() < 2) {
$("div#three").show();
$("div#one").hide();
$("div#two").hide();
$("div#four").hide();
$("div#EM").hide();
}
// early majority
else if ($('input:checked').size() < 4) {
$("div#two").hide();
$("div#one").hide();
$("div#three").hide();
$("div#four").hide();
$("div#EM").show();
}
// early adopter
else if ($('input:checked').size() < 6) {
$("div#two").show();
$("div#one").hide();
$("div#three").hide();
$("div#four").hide();
$("div#EM").hide();
}
else if ($('input:checked').size() < 7) {
$("div#one").show();
$("div#two").hide();
$("div#three").hide();
$("div#four").hide();
$("div#EM").hide();
}
   else {
  // do something here
$("div#four").show();
 $("div#one").hide();
 $("div#two").hide();
 $("div#three").hide();
 $("div#EM").hide();

}
});   
   $('#showMore').click(function() {
  $('#answer').show('slow', function() {
  });
});

    });

</script>
```

Comment: FYI the .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call.

Comment: Expanding upon j08691's answer, .size() is deprecated in the newest version of jQuery (1.8) and will be removed circa 1.9.

Comment: Can you show the markup you're working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason why `Laggard` would show up when all checkboxes are clicked is that you have 7 or more checkboxes.  I created a jsfiddle here.

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/a3Tx8/

Also, Here's a shorter way to write your code

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    var len = $('input:checked').length;  
    $('#four').toggle(len<1 || len > 6);
    $('#three').toggle(len==1);
    $('#two').toggle(len==4 || len==5);
    $('#one').toggle(len==6);
    $('#EM').toggle(len==2 || len==3);
});​
```

Using [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) allows for you to pass in a `condition(true/false)` which determines if it is `shown(true)` or `hidden(false)`

Comment: Thanks in theory this is working, just it's clashing with other toggles on the page, I'll look into it when I have more time though! I'm on my iPad at the moment but would it work better if I take the div hide function out and leave them as display:none?

Comment: when you use hide.. it pretty much makes them display=none..  Also what do you mean by clashing with other toggles?  If you could create an example I can probably help you further